# React Native Dev Setup in Team

Tags: react-native, xcode8

I am currently working in a team developing a react native IOS application, we are all doing this for the first time. I am unable to find any information on development setup with many people working on the same code and we are running into many issues requiring each member to have their own project, and one person with the master project is having to copy and paste code over, any pointers much appreciated!!

Initial project build is successful, the problem occurs when someone else clones the repository and attempts a build. Too many errors to go over and different with each machine. Is there some setup in X-Code or something I am missing with regards to working in a team environment with react native?

Comment: Use version control (Git), work on separate feature branches, and resolve merge conflicts during code reviews and merge requests.

Comment: react-native init ProjectName --> react-native run-ios (all is good) -->push to repository --> other person gets clone --> npm install --> react-native link -->react-native run-ios. At this point the next person does the run-ios the code will not build too many errors to go over. What is happening?

Comment: The process you have described sounds fine to me. It's likely a compatibility issue. E.g. XCode version, Node version, etc. Start working through the errors. Also consider using Yarn, as that uses a lock file to ensure the same package version is installed between machines.

Comment: Will take your advice with Yarn, verifying x-code versions, thank you.

Comment: For others that come across this issue using Yarn rather than Node resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Yarn rather than Node package manager resolved a majority of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Because React native use many libraries like module to help build app fastly and reuse.So, I suggest this workflow to build mobile application with RN.

```
- Use GIT as system version control
- Use IDE (Android Studio, Xcode) to help auto build and fix a lot build error when your team install new libraries and use `react-native link` (ex: react-native-router-flux,...)
- Just push js file to repository and other member can pull it and reload js file. 
- Do it and take a look some repository on github with tutorials
```

Cheer!